# Cast to device context menu is empty, but can cast from YouTube

Tags: video, youtube, screencasts

I can cast from YouTube on my Wi-Fi connected laptop with no problem, but when I right-click an MP4 file and hover over the `Cast to Device` context menu item, I get a never-ending `Searching for devices...` status.

I'm not sure what to make of this. Since I can cast YouTube without any problem, shouldn't I just as easily be able to cast an MP4 video?

How can I watch an MP4 video in the same manner as I watch YouTube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also run into the same problem, of being unable to cast a video
by using Windows.

My solution was to display the video in Chrome and use Chrome's
*Menu > Cast...* command. This method works as well for YouTube,
so might be the one that already works well for you.

Comment: Aha. I tried that and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx3lU.png). So apparently my device only supports certain sources, with Windows not included.